# How to include graphics.h in cxxdroid

Tags: c++, bgi

I want to do graphics.h in cxxdroid says that there is graphics libraries but when I type #include<graphics.h> it says that the file does not exist

Comment: You know, I doubt that you can. Maybe with [SDLBGI](http://libxbgi.sourceforge.net/) serving as the back end, but graphics.h is the header fronting the old Borland Graphics Interface library from the 19-freaking-80s. It provided simple graphics for the DOS operating system. You know, the operating system your grandparents used.

Comment: As for the file not existing, graphics.h is not a C or C++ Standard library header. It was only shipped with the Borland compilers of the 1980s and early 1990s. Any other time you've seen it it's because someone ported the library to a new compiler as an add on. No compiler for close to the last 30 years has had graphics.h built in. You need to find or write a port for your target hardware and add it to your build tools.

Comment: Where I'm going is if you want to develop in 2021 you'll have a much easier time using a tool written in the current millennium like [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) or [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/).